# Rails: How to sum quantities by category in the different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to sum quantities by category in the different models (`Shop` and `Item`).

**models**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shops
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
    has_one :order, autosave: false, through: :shop
end
```

There are the columns `category` and `quantity` in the both `shops` and `items` table as below.

I'd like to sum and display both `quantity` by category.

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160610051929) do

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @orders = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**view/orders/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @orders %>
```

My current view is as follows;

Although it only calculate in `items` table, I'd like to add the quantity in `shops`.

**view/orders/ _order.html.erb**

```
<% order.shops.each do |shop| %>

    <% shop.items.group(:category).sum(:quantity).each do |category, sum| %>

       Category <%=category%> : <%= sum %><br>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Although I also tried the following view instead of the above code, it only works when the `shop`'s category exist in `item`'s category.

If there is no category same as shop's category in the `item`, the result is not what I'd like to.

**view/orders/ _order.html.erb**

```
<% order.shops.each do |shop| %>

    <% shop.items.group(:category).sum(:quantity).each do |category, sum| %>

        <% if shop.category.present? && shop.quantity.present? && category == shop.category %>
            <% sum = sum + shop.quantity %>
        <% end %>

        Category <%=category%> : <%= sum %><br>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to sum and display both quantities or better way.

**SOLVED**

I could do what I'd like to do as followings;

schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "category"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "order_id"
  end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

end
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @orders = Order.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.where(order_id: params[:id])
  end
end
```

_order.html.erb

```
<% order.shops.each do |shop| %>

    <% @categories.where("order_id = ?", order.id).each do |cate| %>
        <%= cate.order_id %>, <%= cate.shop_id%>, <%= cate.item_id%>, <%= cate.category%>, <%= cate.quantity%> <br>
    <% end %>

    <% @categories.where("shop_id = ?", shop.id).group(:category).sum(:quantity).each do |category, sum|%>
    Category <%=category%> : <%= sum %><br>
    <% end %>


<% end %>
```

Comment: Why isn't category is own model? I'm having trouble understanding your why you have your associations that the way you have them: With the current setup there is no straightforward method for doing this sum.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach should work, style-wise you can write it much shorter:

```
sum += shop.quantity.to_i if shop.category == category
```

`nil.to_i` is 0, so no matter if `shop.quantity` is nil or not you can safely add it as long as `shop.category == category` And if `shop.category`is nil, it won't be equal to `category`, so there is no need to ask for it's presence either.

That said, I still think you might want to rethink the way your models are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Leito. Although I created new model called `Category`, I can't figure out how to select the data. I have struggle with this over hours. It may be another (and newbie) question, it would appreciated if you could give me any advice. I updated models and schema.rb. I will delete unnecessary columns later.

Comment: Could you update your question with the latest code? Data? It will help tons if you provide us background on why items and shop have both category and item? I'm having trouble wrapping my head round it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Leito. I can do what I'd like to do. I add the code at the bottom of my answer. Although there may be a better solution, it works what I expected.